# appmaker mismatch error, how do i resolve?

Tags: javascript, google-app-maker, type-mismatch

I have an error and i cant seem to resolve it:

```
Type mismatch: element at [0] should be string, but was: undefined Error: 
Type mismatch: element at [0] should be string, but was: undefined at 
datasources.SitesByld.script:1

Executing query for datasource SitesByld: (Error) : Type mismatch: element 
at [0] should be string, but was: undefined
at datasources.SitesByld.script:1
at Object.success (AppStart:11:14)

Executing query for datasource SitesByld failed.


var record = 
app.models.Sites.getRecord(query.parameters.SitesId);
if (record !== null) {
return [record];
}
return [];
```

I am fairly new to coding so forgive me if this is simple

Comment: Is your query.parameters.SitesId a parameter that includes your (primary) key? The getRecord() function takes the key as your variable, so the only thing I can see is that your key field must be a string field and that you are passing the getRecord() function something other than a string. Might be helpful to clarify what your query.parameters.SitesId is.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your code, you have a if clause but there is no else clause? It seems like the function will always return an empty array.